# Creating ideal temperature for dough to rise

Tags: equipment, bread, dough

Are there machines that maintain optimal temperature for dough to rise?

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/how-do-you-raise-your-dough-in-cold-seasons?rq=1 (almost a dup - it might solve your actual problem - but not actually about machines)

Comment: The machine: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/55906/bread-and-using-a-proofer

Comment: Unless this is for professional/very large scale use, or expected to safely run unattended: What precludes the use of a well calibrated oven (protecting dough surface from direct element heat, obviously!)?

Comment: The correct temperature to proof your bread depends on the result you want. A quick rise in a proofing box makes bread faster, but will less flavor. A long, slow rise give a more flavorful loaf, so IMO the best place to proof bread is the refrigerator.

Comment: @rackandboneman - I don't know about all countries, but in the U.S. it's pretty uncommon to find a new oven that can be set to a temperature below around 170F, which is to prevent food poisoning from people holding food at temperatures below 140F.  Since the optimal temperature for yeast growth is somewhere around 90-95F (higher temps slow it down and 170F will obviously kill yeast), it isn't a practical solution for standard ovens.

Comment: Heh, we need to make a catalog of un-features to avoid when getting new appliances :) I actually thought all ovens still "officially" had their scale starting at 50°C, with there being a lot of 25-50°C to be had between "just oven light" and 50  with millimeter-twiddling the dial ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I'd qualify is as a machine, but they're called either a 'proofer' or a 'proofing box'.

You'll need to check the description, as some boxes are just plastic and are intended to go into a larger proofing room.